# Filter by a threshold value of script_score in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using `cosineSimilarity` in elasticsearch for searching documents and the query looks like the following:

```
{
    "query": {
    "script_score": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "script": {
            "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector, 'title_vector') + 1.0",
            "params": {
                "queryVector": list(feat)
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

The issue here is that I'll be getting all the results despite the similarity score. I want to filter my results based on a threshold filter value.

I tried using `bool` with following script:

```
query = {
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must": {
                        "match_all": {}
                    },
            "filter" : {
                "script" : {
                   
                        "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector, 'title_vector') + 1.0 > 1.4",
    
                        "params": {
                            "queryVector": list(feat)
                         }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this throws an error:

```
RequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', '[source] query malformed, no start_object after query name')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Text similarity search with vector fields](https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch)

**Important limitations**

The script_score query is designed to wrap a restrictive query, and modify the scores of the documents it returns. However, we’ve provided a match_all query, which means the script will be run over all documents in the index. This is a current limitation of vector similarity in Elasticsearch — vectors can be used for scoring documents, but not in the initial retrieval step. Support for retrieval based on vector similarity is an important area of ongoing work.

**EDIT**

Adding `min_score` to the request will filter out based on the calculated score **after doing the match_all**.

```
{
  "min_score": 1.4,
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector, 'title_vector') + 1.0",
        "params": {
          "queryVector": list(feat)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's ok if it does matches all, and shouldn't it be doing the same if I'm trying to find similarity with all my indexes? What I'm looking for is, filtering my resulting post the matching process.

Comment: @NikhilPareek What about adding "min_score" , like this :

{
"min_score": 1.4,
    "query": {
    "script_score": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "script": {
            "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector, 'title_vector') + 1.0",
            "params": {
                "queryVector": list(feat)
            }
        }
    }
}}

Comment: Thanks. This solved the issue. Btw, I could.t find this on documentation.